# ComboBox not displaying value in windows pone 8.0

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, combobox

I am trying to display values of all items present in a comboBox. The items are displaying as list after running the emulator.In addition, the combobox is not clickable to select an item.

```
 <ComboBox FontWeight="Bold" x:Name="FStyle" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="192,435,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="27" Width="154" SelectionChanged="FStyle_SelectionChanged">
              <ComboBoxItem Content="Normal"/>
              <ComboBoxItem Content="Italic" />

  </ComboBox>
```

What could be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's stupid but ...

Remove that killing margin and set Height to auto, also as a general tip for future never hardcode Height and Width, but try to position controls in containers controls.

Good luck.

Comment: ooh sir this is what have done  and still not working

Comment: <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="57" Margin="192,435,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="154">

            <ComboBox FontWeight="Bold" x:Name="FStyle" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top"   SelectionChanged="FStyle_SelectionChanged">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Normal"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Italic" />

            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>

Comment: When I copy/paste your XAML code into sample WPhone project  it is working without any problem. Please describe again what is not working for you?

Comment: I think their is a problem with my visual studio  ... Thanks for your concern